# Drop-down menu on tablet

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, tablet

I've got a test website with drop-down menu that works perfectly fine on desktops and laptops, but when viewed on an iPad for example, in landscape mode where the media queries haven't kicked in, you can still view the website as you would on a desktop, but the drop down menus don't function properly and I wonder if anyone knows how I can fix this.

Because there's no hover option on an iPad, is there some code I can apply that kicks in on tablets? At the moment you can only click on the top link, and once you do it reveals the drop-down for a second before loading the page that the top link goes to.

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: Really need to know more than what you've provided... Have you included the viewport meta tag for example? A look at your code would help.